# This webpage has a redirect loop "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" in chrome and all browser in php code

Tags: php

my code is in php written as.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['pp_group'])){
session_destroy();
@header("Location:../login");
exit();
}
```

Comment: could be something in `.htaccess` and/or something else in other files we don't know about, including what you posted for code that stands to miss a lot of code.

Comment: Why are you using `@` at your header?

Comment: When i delete my all cookies from browser then this error has solved. But user don't know that things, so i want to fix this for all user.

Comment: @ is used for preventing the errors messages.

Comment: ....errr.... you want to remove it during testing. Btw, the LESS we know, the MORE time it takes to offer a solution. We also don't know if you started the session or not etc. etc. etc............................ You're actually wasting everyone's time here, including "yours".

Comment: You're destroying the session based on a cookie, but whenever that cookie is set you'll always be destroying the session. Shouldn't you unset the cookie too?

Comment: Also, you should handle the error instead of ignoring them, the `@` doesn't prevent errors, it just hides them.

Comment: Thanks you all for give me your vital time to solved this issue, specially @Fred -ii-. I solved this by delete all cookie just after destroying session.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to see you found the root of the problem, *cheers*

Answer (score 2):

You have to delete all your cookie names to redirect to desired url:

```
if(empty($_COOKIE['pp_group'])){
    session_destroy();
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
    header("Location: ../login/index.php");
    exit();
}
```